# Updating Data Dynamically in Chartjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js

I am trying to update my charts in react with a click of a button. The button will switch the data used in the chart. I am able to connect the button to the chart, however, I am unable to use update() to re-render the chart and it tells me that update() is not a function even though I have Chart imported?

```
const TestChart = () => {
    function addData() {
        current = CityCases
        */ update would go here */
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <Bar
                data={{
                    labels: Labels,
                    datasets: [
                        {
                            label: 'County',
                            data: CountyCases,

                            /*backgroundColor: [
                                '#E3DD34',
                                '#78496B',
                                '#F0527F',
                                '#E0EFF0',
                                '#A7E0E2'
                            ],*/

                            backgroundColor: [
                                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)'
                            ],

                            borderColor: [
                                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)'
                            ],

                            borderWidth: 1,
                        },

                        {
                            label: 'City',
                            data: currentCityCases,

                            backgroundColor: [
                                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)'
                            ],

                            borderColor: [
                                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)'
                            ],

                            borderWidth: 1,
                        },
                    ],
                }}
                height={400}
                width={600}
                options={{
                    responsiveAnimationDuration: 1050,
                    title: {
                        display: true,
                        text: 'Cases',
                        fontSize: 30,
                        /*fontColor: "whitesmoke"*/
                    },

                    legend: {
                        labels: {
                            fontSize: 15,
                            /*fontColor: "rgba(255,255,255,0.65)",*/
                        }
                    },
                    maintainAspectRatio: false,
                    scales: {
                        yAxes: [
                            {
                                /*gridLines: {
                                    color: "rgba(255,255,255,0.45)"
                                },*/
                                ticks: {
                                    /*fontColor: "rgba(255,255,255,0.45)",*/
                                    fontSize: 18,
                                    beginAtZero: true,
                                },
                            },
                        ],

                        xAxes: [
                            {
                                /*gridLines: {
                                    color: "rgba(255,255,255,0.45)"
                                },*/
                                ticks: {
                                    /*fontColor: "rgba(255,255,255,0.45)",*/
                                    fontSize: 18,
                                }
                            },
                        ]
                    },
                }}
            />
            <input type="button" value="Normal" onClick={() => addData()}></input>
        </div>

    )
}
```

Here is how I import it into my other page, the button created in TestChart is rendered with it, the other buttons were just dummy ones created and are separate. Forgive me if some parts are a little weird looking, I was trying to take out some lines to hide my location and information. The main issue at hand is just trying to use the update() function.

```
import TestChart from "../components/TestChart"

function Data() {
    return (
        <div className='data'>
            <div className="bigContainer">
                <div className="buttonContainer">
                    <input type="button" value="Data"></input>
                    <input type="button" value="Data"></input>
                    <input type="button" value="Data"></input>
                </div>
                <div className="chartContainer">
                    <RaceCaseChart />
                </div>
            </div> ........
```